# Python: All possible combinations of a list of numbers (cryptography)

Tags: python, list, loops, cryptography, python-itertools

1. I want to find **all the possible combinations** of a `list of numbers`:
   replacing each number from right to left with the numbers 0 to 9,
   iterating until the script found a **valid number**, kinda like a chronometer from right to left,
2. **but** you have to do the same with new combination as a **new number to check**.

**Part 1:**
**I tried this function to iterate:**

```
def makeIters(cc, n):
    for i in range(len(cc) - 1, -1, -1):
        yield from (cc[:i] + [str(num)] + cc[i+1:] for num in n)
```

`cc` (stands for credit_card) is the `list` of numbers and `n` is the `check` list that go from 0 to 9.
This function complete the first part:
**For example:**
As **input**, If I have credit card number `cc = [1, 2, 3]` (always using the check list that goes from 0 to 9),

```
combinations = []
check = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
cc = [1, 2, 3]

for possible_combinations in makeIters(cc, check):
  combinations.append(possible_combinations)
  print(combinations)
```

the **output** will be something like:

```
ROWS:
  A        B        C  
1 2 0  | 1 0 3  | 0 2 3  
1 2 1  | 1 1 3  | 1 2 3
1 2 2  | 1 2 3  | 2 2 3
1 2 3  | 1 3 3  | 3 2 3
1 2 4  | 1 4 3  | 4 2 3 
1 2 5  | 1 5 3  | 5 2 3
1 2 6  | 1 6 3  | 6 2 3
1 2 7  | 1 7 3  | 7 2 3
1 2 8  | 1 8 3  | 8 2 3
1 2 9  | 1 9 3  | 9 2 3
```

But If if the number I'm looking for is `3 0 1` or `3 1 0`, or `2 2 2`, this will not work.

**Part 2:**
Therefore, If I want to find this numbers, I have to do the same that I did with the function with every number generated

**Example for the part 2:**

> valid number: 3 1 0

**Input:**

```
check = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
cc = [1, 2, 3]
```

**output:**
In order to find `3 1 0` we will use as example the `Row C`, must apply to every row, though):**

```
     C   | C.d (323)| C.d.a(320) 
a. 0 2 3 | 3 2 0    | 3 1 0 valid_number_found 
b. 1 2 3 | 3 2 1    | 
c. 2 2 3 | 3 2 2    | 
d. 3 2 3 | 3 2 3    | 
e. 4 2 3 | 3 2 4    | 
f. 5 2 3 | 3 2 5    | 
g. 6 2 3 | 3 2 6    | 
h. 7 2 3 | 3 2 7    | 
i. 8 2 3 | 3 2 8    | 
j. 9 2 3 | 3 2 9    |
```

*Hint: in the examples I use cc with lenght of 3 numbers, but the the numbers that I must find are with lengt 16.*

Comment: Why do you not simply use `itertools.permutations([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3)` or `itertools.combinations(...)`?

Comment: @shotgunner Because is not what I'm looking for. The check list is to iterate each element of the list of random numbers. The list can be list = [random numbers with lenght=16]

Comment: ok, then how about [`itertools.product(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: I have the idea that this is a very interesting question, but I still don't get what you're asking for. There is a lot of confusion in the question. You are talking about two lists, but you don't really explain what they contain or what names they have. The second list is used to check, but then you have two lists called `check` and `list` introduced. You don't explain *what* is being checked, etc. You've got code that is likely not fully correct, but you don't indicate how it fails. So maybe I'm missing something obvious, but the question can certainly be made more clear.

Comment: I cannot discern the logic of the problem from the input/output example, and it seems others can't either. Please edit the question to explain precisely what you are trying to do.

Comment: I agree with @Maarten-reinstateMonica. This question could be good, but isn't at the moment. It needs editing with more information.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica,, thank you for your critics, my main language is not english, but I improve the question.

Comment: @kaya3 question improved

Comment: @Legorooj, thank you, question improved